# PHP Initialize one class with multiple variables multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class

I am trying to run a database class that can contact multiple databases. I have it set up like this:

```
$auth = new Auth($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['name']['api'], $db['pass']['api']);
$apiuser = new APIUser($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['name']['users'], $db['pass']['users']);
```

All those $db array variables work correctly, but it's the class that doesn't. In each class's __construct function, I have this:

```
function __construct($dbh, $dbu, $dbn, $dbp) {

        $this->db = new DB($dbh, $dbu, $dbn, $dbp);
    }
```

However, when I try to run $this->db->query("my query here"); (which contains a simple return mysql_query with the input variable), it returns a boolean not a resource ID... This is because the class is reverting to the users database instead of the api database since $apiuser comes after $apiauth...

If that makes any sense at all, I really could use some help on this! Thanks!

EDIT: Part of the DB class giving the errors:

```
function __construct($host, $user, $name, $pass) {
        $this->error = new Error();
        if(!mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)) {
            $this->error->db_connect_error($host, $user, $pass);
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($name)) {
            $this->error->db_select_error($name);
        }
    }
    function query($input) {
        return mysql_query($input);
    }
```

Comment: it would be nice to see the DB class as well

Comment: just posted it, thanks!

Comment: i'd say that's kind of bad practice to return the $resource directly, it'd probably be better to return the actual results. anyways if its returning FALSE, that means either: 1. your query has an error 2. db connection has an error 3. the given user doesn't have permission to access the table.

Comment: You should just be passing your `DB` instance as the argument. Dependency injection, DRY, etc. Also no duplicate instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I try to run $this->db->query("my query here"); (which contains a simple return mysql_query with the input variable), it returns a boolean not a resource ID... This is because the class is reverting to the users database instead of the api database since $apiuser comes after $apiauth...

If youre using multiple DB's then you need to specify the link youre using:

```
class DB {
   private $dbRsrc;

   function __construct($host, $user, $name, $pass) {
        $this->error = new Error();
        $this->dbRsrc = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
        if(!$this->dbRsrc) {
            $this->error->db_connect_error($host, $user, $pass);
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($name)) {
            $this->error->db_select_error($name);
        }
    }
    function query($input) {
        return mysql_query($input, $this->dbRsrc);
    }
}
```

That said you should really inject the `DB` instance into the other classes as @WaleedKahn suggests. Furthermore you shouldnt be using the `mysql_*` functions. Use [`Mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Both already have an object oriented interface.